TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') while running `yarn hardhat deploy`
I really, really need help, please
I am studying Web3 on YouTube (Learn Blockchain, Solidity, and Full Stack Web3 Development with JavaScript – 32-Hour Course
), and now it is Lesson 9: Hardhat Smart Contract Lottery.
I have encountered a very strange problem and have been searching for a solution for a long time.
After running yarn hardhat deploy, the result is as follows:
taufik@YOGA-Taufik:~/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc$ hh deploy
Nothing to compile
Local network detected! Deploying mocks...
deploying "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock" (tx: 0xd7c7dc9cc8ab82f01de02b3626f98c1f7d928b1f9f89c9129efc145d07f02ab6)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 2967891 gas
Mocks Deployed!
----------------------------------------------------------
You are deploying to a local network, you'll need a local network running to interact
Please run `yarn hardhat console --network localhost` to interact with the deployed smart contracts!
----------------------------------------------------------
Contract {
  target: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [
      [ConstructorFragment], [ErrorFragment],
      [ErrorFragment],       [ErrorFragment],
      [ErrorFragment],       [ErrorFragment],
      [ErrorFragment],       [ErrorFragment],
      [EventFragment],       [EventFragment],
      [EventFragment],       [EventFragment],
      [EventFragment],       [EventFragment],
      [EventFragment],       [EventFragment],
      [EventFragment],       [EventFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],    [FunctionFragment]
    ],
    deploy: ConstructorFragment {
      type: 'constructor',
      inputs: [Array],
      payable: false,
      gas: null
    },
    fallback: null,
    receive: false
  },
  runner: HardhatEthersSigner {
    _gasLimit: 30000000,
    address: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    provider: HardhatEthersProvider {
      _hardhatProvider: [LazyInitializationProviderAdapter],
      _networkName: 'hardhat',
      _blockListeners: [],
      _transactionHashListeners: Map(0) {},
      _eventListeners: []
    }
  },
  filters: {},
  fallback: null,
  [Symbol(_ethersInternal_contract)]: {}
}
=================================================
undefined
=================================================
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing /home/taufik/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/deploy/01-deploy-raffle.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

The reason is because vrfCoordinatorV2Address cannot obtain the address.
But vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, it's normal, why is that
01-deploy-raffle.js
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const FUND_AMOUNT = "1000000000000000000"

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (chainId == 31337) {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        //log(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock)
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        // log(vrfCoordinatorV2Address)
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)

        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        // Fund the subscription
        // Our mock makes it so we don't actually have to worry about sending fund
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    const waitBlockConfirmations = developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? 1
        : VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS

    log("----------------------------------------------------")
    const arguments = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        subscriptionId,
        networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["raffleEntranceFee"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"],
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: arguments,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
    })

    // Ensure the Raffle contract is a valid consumer of the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract.
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, raffle.address)
    }

    // Verify the deployment
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, arguments)
    }

    log("Enter lottery with command:")
    const networkName = network.name == "hardhat" ? "localhost" : network.name
    log(`yarn hardhat run scripts/enterRaffle.js --network ${networkName}`)
    log("----------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]


00-deploy-mocks.js
const { network } = require("hardhat")

const BASE_FEE = "250000000000000000" // 0.25 is this the premium in LINK?
const GAS_PRICE_LINK = 1e9 // link per gas, is this the gas lane? // 0.000000001 LINK per gas

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    // If we are on a local development network, we need to deploy mocks!
    if (chainId == 31337) {
        log("Local network detected! Deploying mocks...")
        await deploy("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", {
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [BASE_FEE, GAS_PRICE_LINK],
        })

        log("Mocks Deployed!")
        log("----------------------------------------------------------")
        log("You are deploying to a local network, you'll need a local network running to interact")
        log(
            "Please run `yarn hardhat console --network localhost` to interact with the deployed smart contracts!",
        )
        log("----------------------------------------------------------")
    }
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]

VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol";


Raffle.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol";

error Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__RaffleNotOpen();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

/**
 * @title A sample Raffle Contract
 * @author Taufik
 */

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /* Type declarations */
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    }

    /* State variables */
    uint private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_keyHash;
    uint64 private immutable i_subId;
    uint16 private constant MINI_REQUEST = 3;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    // Lottery Variables
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    address private s_recentWinner;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;

    /* Events */
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed player);

    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint entranceFee,
        bytes32 keyHash,
        uint64 subId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_keyHash = keyHash;
        i_subId = subId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
        }
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__RaffleNotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        // Emit an event when we update a dynamic array or mapping
        // Named events with the function name reversed
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that the Chainlink Keeper nodes call
     * they look for `upkeepNeeded` to return True.
     * the following should be true for this to return true:
     * 1. The time interval has passed between raffle runs.
     * 2. The lottery is open.
     * 3. The contract has ETH.
     * 4. Implicity, your subscription is funded with LINK.
     */
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    ) public view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        bool isOpen = RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState;
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = s_players.length > 0;
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (timePassed && isOpen && hasBalance && hasPlayers);
        return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0"); // can we comment this out?
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external {
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_keyHash,
            i_subId,
            MINI_REQUEST, // uint16 minimumRequestConfirmations,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS // uint32 numWords
        );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256,
        /* requestId */ uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        // s_players size 10
        // randomNumber 202
        // 202 % 10 ? what's doesn't divide evenly into 202?
        // 20 * 10 = 200
        // 2
        // 202 % 10 = 2
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    /**
     * Getter Functions
     */
    function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
        return s_raffleState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return NUM_WORDS;
    }

    // function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
    //     return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
    // }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getLastTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }
}


Can you share the GitHub repo of your codebase?

@SYED ASAD KAZMI
Thank you, I really need help.
myGithub
Then I realized that it might be this reason, I found it on the official GitHub of the tutorial.
log("Please run `yarn hardhat console --network localhost` to interact with the deployed smart contracts!")

On line 22 of 00-deploy-mocks.js

In your 01-deploy-raffle.js, you need to get the address of the deployed vrfCoordinatorV2Mock (i.e., deployed through 00-deploy-mocks.js)  using await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.getAddress() instead of vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address.
And, you need to get the subscriptionId from the transactionReceipt using transactionReceipt.logs[0].args.subId instead of transactionReceipt. events[0].args.subId, i.e., by replacing events with logs.
Here's the revised 01-deploy-raffle.js file:
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const FUND_AMOUNT = "1000000000000000000"

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (chainId == 31337) {

        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        //log(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock)

        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.getAddress()

        // log(vrfCoordinatorV2Address)
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)

        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.logs[0].args.subId
        // Fund the subscription
        // Our mock makes it so we don't actually have to worry about sending fund
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT)
    }

    else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    const waitBlockConfirmations = developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? 1
        : VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS

    log("----------------------------------------------------")
    const arguments = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        subscriptionId,
        networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["raffleEntranceFee"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"],
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: arguments,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
    })

    // Ensure the Raffle contract is a valid consumer of the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract.
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, raffle.address)
    }

    // Verify the deployment
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, arguments)
    }

    log("Enter lottery with command:")
    const networkName = network.name == "hardhat" ? "localhost" : network.name
    log(`yarn hardhat run scripts/enterRaffle.js --network ${networkName}`)
    log("----------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]



Thank you very much. This issue has been resolved, and I want to celebrate it.
@SYED ASAD KAZMI

You’re welcome, @Taufik. Keep building!
